# Update NGINX version in Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My container is running NGINX 1.24.0, I am trying to update the NGINX version to 1.25 but when I am trying to update the NGINX version inside the container using "apt-get install nginx" it is saying the latest version is already installed?

How to update the nginx version inside the container?

docker exec -it  /bin/bash to get inside the container file system and run apt-get install nginx to update nginx

Comment: Hello Soumodeep Saha. This is not a programming question, rather a configuration question. As such it is likelier to be answered in other stack exchanges. Possibly [server fault](https://serverfault.com/). Good luck.

Comment: That being said, you should add data to your question. What is the base image of your docker container? Did you build it?

Answer (score 0):

> trying to update the NGINX version inside the container using "apt-get install nginx"

i assume that you are using the official nginx image, thus you should not update nginx within the image but rather use an official image with the version that you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Updating a docker-container with `docker exec ...` is never a good idea. These updates are not persistent and will be lost, when the docker container stops.

## But ... howto update?

Best answer, it depends. You wrote no information which image you are using. So there are two variants.

### Own docker-image

If you have your own [dockerfile](/questions/tagged/dockerfile) which looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt install nginx
...
```

then you just have to do a `docker build . -t myImage:tag`.

### Official [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) [docker-image](/questions/tagged/docker-image)

When you use the official nginx image, then the current version is marked by the tag.

- `docker run nginx:latest` will run always the newest version. It will change over time.
- `docker run nginx:1.25.2` will run the current latest version (this image will be always the same).
- `docker run nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.25` will run always the latest rootless `1.25` version. It will change, when small updates/hotfixes are provided.

You can force an update by running `docker pull nginx/...`.
Remember, you have then to stop & start all your nginx [docker-container](/questions/tagged/docker-container).